# Converting string to char array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have something like the below:

```
char[] array = new char[5];
String a = "HELLO";
String b = "WORLD";
array[0] = a.toCharArray();
array[1] = b.toCharArray();
```

I get error "incompatible types, char[] cannot be converted to char". My final product I'd like something like the below:

```
array = {{H},{E},{L},{L},{O}},{{W},{O},{R},{L},{D}};
```

`array` becomes a `[2][5]` array in the end result. Is `toCharArray()` the incorrect method to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a double array.  Something like

```
char[][] arr = new char[2][];
arr[0] = a.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Well...you can't have a jagged array without a defined row size.

Comment: @makoto36 yeah, mental slip up there!

Comment: I feel so silly for overlooking something so simple. All the best, this worked. Just curious, and while this is only somewhat related, how do I check the length of a ragged array? Something like a two-dimensional array with undefined lengths, how do I check the length of individual sub-arrays? array.length will give the number of elements in main arrays, will array[].length give the lengths of inner arrays?

Comment: @riista No, however you could you use arr[0].length to get the length of the first element, but you need to do that one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You need an array of arrays.  Something like this:

```
char[][] array = new char[5][];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `toCharArray` to get a `char[]` back; the problem is where you put it after you extract it.

Change your `array` variable to be a `char[][]`, and define it as such:

```
char[][] array = new char[2][5];
```

Note that the result won't *exactly* be `{{H},{E},{L},{L},{O}},{{W},{O},{R},{L},{D}}`; it'd be more like `{{H, E, L, L, O}},{{W, O, R, L ,D}}`.

Answer (score 1):

You need an array of arrays

```
char[][] arr = new char[5][];
arr[0] = a.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] array = new char[5];
String a = "HELLO";
String b = "WORLD";
array[0] = a.toCharArray();
array[1] = b.toCharArray();
```

What if a and b are not of the same length ? Your method and the ones proposed by others are very limited/specific and not flexible. Try this instead to make abstraction of the length of the String.

```
 ArrayList<char[]> array = new ArrayList();
 String a = "HELLO";
 String b = "WORLD";
 array.add(a.toCharArray());
 array.add(b.toCharArray());
```